# Why do I get a "Possible null pointer dereference" warning?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, findbugs

Why do FindBugs raises me the following warning: *[Possible null pointer dereference](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH)*.

```
current = myService.getCategoryParent(current);
if (current != null) { // The warning appears here
```

I don't understand how testing a variable against null could dereference it.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt It's a custom `Category` class

Comment: Is current used at all after/outside of this if-statement?

Comment: @BeRecursive: It's used on the line above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah yes that would make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the error/warning is actually on the line *above* the line you've indicated.

```
//                   here ------------v
current = myService.getCategoryParent(current);
if (current != null) {
```

Comment: Sonar reports the warning on the second line, but I added the line above just to be sure because I also have a doubt... If that was the case, then what would the warning be about?

Comment: @Matthieu: Presumably it's worried that `getCategoryParent` is going to dereference the argument passed in? Does `getCategoryParent` have a `!null` check?

Comment: Yes there is a `!=null` check. However `getCategoryParent` can return `null`, may that be it?

Comment: @Matthieu: `getCategoryParent` returning `null` isn't a problem, because you've got the `null` check just after you call it. As an experiment, I recommend putting 10 `System.out.println("foo");` lines between the two lines you've quoted, and running FindBugs again, just in case there's an oboe (off-by-one error) in its line number reporting. Just to narrow down which line it's actually warning about.